# disk cloning - issue with disk naming and boot

Tags: windows-10, disk-cloning, cloning

I cloned my internal HDD into a samsung 990 Pro using clonezilla. I am on Windows 10 and both disks are internal. When I open disk management, the old drive "Windows (C:)" shows 476 GB NTFS (Bitlocker Encrypted) Healthy (Boot, Crash Dump, Primary Partition), the new drive "Windows (D:)" shows 488 GB NTFS (Bitlocker Encrypted) Healthy (Page File, Primary Partition. I have already set the paging file to None on the C: drive and System managed on D: but I still can't change the partition names as I need to name the new one C: after I name the old one something else. trying to do so on disk management gives me an error (The parameter is incorrect). I can't make the new one bootable despite placing it first on the list in the Boot/bios drive order.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP notes they were unable to solve the issue and did a fresh install. As the problem can no longer be replicated, this question should be closed.